# Could somebody explain the difference between these ways to make food directly using fire or heat?

Tags: terminology

When you use fire or head directly to cook or make something, there are so many different ways, like grill, roast, toast, bake and broil, maybe there are more else. What is difference between them?

Comment: All words for common foods are intensely local, and American uses of _barbecue_ as noun, verb, participle, and adjective are a perfect example. The term alone refers to quite different kinds of meat preparation, all involving heat, but with no other common distinguishing characteristics except a profusion of secret recipes. What they call _barbecue_ in N. Carolina is very different from what they call _barbecue_ in Texas, for instance. _BBQ_ is just an abbreviation for whatever _barbecue_ means in the area.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said, though I believe that the apparatus used for all those variations is still a grill, usually an outdoor device that uses charcoal briquettes, propane gas or wood to cook the food.  Because a grill is usually (though not always) enclosed with a lid, the heating chamber can also be used to bake and roast the food while an open grill can "grill", charbroil, sear, and toast food.  If you add a pot or pan to the grill surface, you can add boiling, sauté-ing, braising and steaming to the list of cook methods.

Comment: In some places there is no grill, but rather a smoker. Direct or indirect heat, smoke or no smoke, picante or not, vinegar or sugar, rubbed or marinated, ... the list goes on, almost indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers. I think my question was not very clear, I changed the title and question a little. What I really want to know is the difference between grill, roast, toast, bake and broil etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Your amended question is way too broad for anyone to answer. Read the dictionary definitions, and a few cookbooks.

Comment: Many of these words have basic meanings (_bake_ is to cook in an oven, _broil_ is to cook from the top, _toast_ to heat until crunchy, etc.). Problem is, like many other English words, these words are flexible, can take on several different meanings. I don't toast marshmallows the same way I toast bagels. _Grill_ and _toast_ can mean radically different things, or be almost synonymous (as in the case of grilled cheese sandwiches). I think this question is too broad. You might also check out [cooking.SE], the cooking site, but I wouldn't ask about so many words at one time on either site.

Comment: Your original question said that you are not a native English speaker. In that case, have you tried looking up the words in a dual-language dictionary that would translate the English words into your native language. Or look them up in an English dictionary, or consult a cooking web-site. Then you could come back with more specific queries about individual terms that you are still confused about, which would be much easier to answer.  Also, Have you looked at out sister site [ell.se]?

Comment: Cooking.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more appropriate/ better asked on cookingSE

Comment: I looked up them in dictionary, their  meanings are almost the same in Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

I think John Lawler has the run of it.

*BBQ* can be a noun, a verb, or something else.  In fact, one can barbeque something on a barbeque with barbeque sauce.

In very general terms, barbequing is apply heat to meat.  But there are barbequed vegetables, and as pointed out, the "heat" may or may not involve flame, smoke, wood, electricity, etc....

In practical usage as a nonnative speaker, if someone invites you over for a barbeque, they want to feed you and you should go.  You may be served hamburgers prepared over charcoal in a Weber kettle, you may be served marinated chicken from a gas grill, you may be served pulled pork from a smoker.  All would likely be termed BBQ, all would likely be quite good, and the time spent determining what exactly is and isn't barbeque better spent eating what is being offered.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures speak louder than words. However, sometimes a little more detail is useful and I found a website, [**Chasing Delicious**](http://chasingdelicious.com/kitchen-101-cooking-methods/#prettyPhoto/0/), which explains in detail the various cooking methods.

E.g:

> **Baking** refers to the cooking method that requires cooking in an
>   enclosed space with dry heat. In conventional ovens, stagnant dry heat
>   surrounds the baked-good cooking it evenly (hopefully) from all sides.
>   In convection ovens, dry heat is circulated around the baked good with
>   a fan; the baked-good is again cooked evenly from all sides but here
>   it is cooked quicker and often far more precisely than a conventional
>   oven can.

[image]
[image]
[image]